# Makeindex: Bibleref–Eledmac-Incompatibility?

Tags: memoir, indexing, eledmac

If I compile the following tex-document makeindex produces wrong index entries (always the last line of the page is referenced). What's the reason for it and is there a way to solve this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{bibleref}
\makeindex[bibel]
\renewcommand{\biblerefindex}{\edindex[bibel]}
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \edtext{consectetuer}{\Bfootnote{\ibibleverse{Gen}(1:1)}} adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. \edtext{Praesent}{\Afootnote{Present \textit{A}}} imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus.
Pellentesque placerat. Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit
amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent blandit blandit mauris.
Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit \edtext{amet}{\Bfootnote{\ibibleverse{Dan}(5:1)}} ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum
turpis accumsan semper.
\pend
\pstart
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam
lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a
dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie
ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit. Ut porttitor. Praesent in
sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Duis fringilla tristique \edtext{neque}{\Bfootnote{\ibibleverse{Mt}(12:1)}}. 
\pend
\endnumbering
\printindex[bibel]
\end{document}
```

I'm using:

- memoir.cls    2013/05/22 v3.7 configurable book, report, article document cla
  ss
- eledmac.sty    2013/04/15 v1.4.6 LaTeX port of EDMAC
- bibleref.sty    2011/01/19 1.14 (NLCT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem in eledmac. I will correct it tomorrow (or after tomorrow).

Cf https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/113

Comment: So, the version 1.5 have just been uploaded in CTAN